# Error 'Invalid geography. Antipodal edge...' with Postgis

Tags: qgis, layers, postgis-2.0, antipodal

I have a table in postgis like this

```
CREATE TABLE locations (id int, name VARCHAR(255), pos geography(POINT, 4326));
```

with a couple of points. E.G.

```
INSERT INTO locations (name, pos) VALUES ('freiburg', ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(7.86 48.0)'));
```

But importing the table as a layer in Qgis results in multiple errors

```
Query: DECLARE qgisf0_0 BINARY CURSOR FOR SELECT 
st_asbinary(st_force_2d("pos"::geometry),'NDR'),"id" FROM 
"public"."locations" WHERE "pos" && st_makeenvelope(-180,-90,180,90,4326) 
returned 7 [ERROR:  Invalid geography. Antipodal (180 degrees long) edge 
(180 -90,180 90) detected, add a point between to make two edges that span 
less than 180 degrees.]
```

and nothing gets drawn.

My QGis is 1.9.0, postgis 2.0.3

Comment: Is your id field a primary key or a unique index?

Comment: @DPierce: Im my example it is just a int field. As I thought it's non relevant to my problem. Anyway, using 'serial' or omitting the column completely does not make the error go away. I just gave it a try.

Comment: I'll admit that it seems eroneous, but QGIS requires a unique non-null fields for PostGIS queries. Have you check to make sure nothing in the table has an anti-podal points? Those are banned in PostGIS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the unique field.

I have narrowed my data down to that one entry. I think the error is not in my data but in the st_makeenvelope(...) call QGIS uses to grab all data.

Comment: Pretty sure this is just a bug. See: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/geometry-with-geography-type-column-not-displayed-td4690688.html#a4690860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in QGIS.

Bug report http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8572

Comment: Yeah, QGIS is going to need to be a smidge smarter dealing with geography types. The world is not a rectangle.

Comment: bug still crawling at v2.6